# Should initialisation of class-level variable with by lazy in Kotlin be avoided because it prevents Unit Testing?

Tags: kotlin

Having a class-level variable and instantiating the object at the same time creates a problem for Unit Testing because you can't really mock the dependency.

Does this mean the Kotlin feature `by lazy` should be avoided as it hinders proper unit testing, or is there a way to overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `lazy` is just a `val` that gets initialised later - if you need to change all your `val`s to `var`s so you can poke around at them while testing, that's probably a bad sign.

If your `lazy` is creating objects, then that's where dependency injection comes in - pass in the dependency, or something that provides the dependency, and then you can mock that when the lazy initialiser calls it.

If you're just trying to change the internal state so you can test a particular scenario, that's trickier. Ideally with a unit test you're testing the behaviour of a single component, and how it interacts with other things - if it provides the expected input and output. You shouldn't need to poke around at the internals, at least not in a way that isn't already part of the design and part of the expected use case.

But sometimes you want to recreate state, which is possible using the normal API, but takes a lot of code. That's a trickier call when the component isn't already designed that way - if it's that important, you might want to make it configurable, either through constructor parameters or by passing in some kind of config object.

Making things `public` that should be `private` just for testing is usually a sign that you should find another way to do your test. Changing a `val` to a `var` just for testing is especially bad, because it breaks the usual immutability guarantees and now your code has to handle all the "possibly changed" warnings even though you know it's *really* a `val`. I don't think `lazy` really makes much difference here - it's just a fancy getter, an internal implementation detail. I think your issues are more down to how the code is structured, and injecting your dependencies will probably help a lot